# How to loop through tweepy's status.entities path using a variable as value?

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy's streamlistener to parse tweets and store several of their attributes.

In most instances, certain elements of the tweet, i.e. hashtags and urls are stored under the entities section, for example:

```
status.entities['hashtags']
status.entities['mentions']
```

I'm trying to access these values for the attributes I'm interested in using a for loop as below:

```
attributes = [hashtags, mentions,urls, media]

for attr in attributes:
    try:
        attr = status.entities['attr']
        # the normal path would be : attr = status.entities['hashtags']
    except:
        # look somewhere else i.e.
        attr = status.extended_entities['hashtags']
```

How can I replace the `'hashtags'` string above using members of my attributes list so that I can get the loop to work?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the value of the variable *attr* in your for loop, so don't enclose it within single quotations. Also don't reuse the variable name *attr* to store the return value.

```
info = status.entities[attr]
```